# Cannot stream video to xbox through wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, video, streaming, xbox360

Here's my current setup:
[image: current setup]

Streaming video to the xbox worked great when I had my PC connected to the router using a wired connection (cat 5e 100mbps). But, now that the pc is wireless and actually has a faster connection speed, I cannot stream video for some reason.

If I try to use Windows Media Center, I always get an error. If I try using the video library and connecting to a file share on the computer, video will play but it's so choppy that it's not viewable.

I have isolated devices, turned off firewalls, and disabled antivirus. Nothing has worked.

Does anyone have a similar setup? Suggestions?

Comment: i had a similar issue myself. unfortunately i never did solve it :-\

Comment: Just because you are connected via wireless n does not mean you are going faster then the direct wire. Check signal strength, competing signals, what not.

Answer (score 0):

If there are a lot of other routers in the area, try changing the channel to 1 or 11, instead of the default 6.

If every wireless device is N, you can force all connections to be N. This will help highlight any speed reductions.

Wireless speeds are gauged by both up AND down speeds. If the Win7 machine isn't the only machine on the network, it's possible that you're using up all the bandwidth. For example, with 270mbps, you get a total of 135 up and 135 down at the same time. Start splitting that up over several connections, and it can get a little choppy.